# How to set a defined horizontal padding between \includegraphics images

Tags: spacing, graphics, horizontal-alignment, horizontal

How can I set a fixed horizontal padding between my images?
I'm using (in my master file):

`\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}`

With this in my included file:

`\newcommand{\vastehoogte}[1]{\includegraphics[height=1\textheight,keepaspectratio]{#1}}`

to insert images this way:

```
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=1\textwidth}

        \vastehoogte{1.JPG}
        \vastehoogte{2.JPG}
        \vastehoogte{3.JPG}
        \vastehoogte{4.JPG}
        \vastehoogte{7.JPG}
        \vastehoogte{8.JPG}

        \end{adjustbox} 

\par}
```

However I cannot seem to get a few mm's of padding between the images with vspace or something else. Can someone help me?

Comment: Did you try some horizontal space?  Like `\thinspace` or `\quad` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried `\quad` in multiple places/formattings (I have to admit, I'm very very new to Latex) and it worked. But when I zoomed in on my PDF, I noticed there was this `\quad` in text on the PDF (at 100% zoom it just looked like a small line).

Comment: whatever you could see would not be from `\quad` as that just makes a space. Your question would be a lot clearer if you had shown what you had done rather than say you added some unspecified commands in unspecified places which didn't work. You appear to be wanting horizontal space but you said you tried `\vspace` which is for vertical space? Also it is not clear what is the intent of the outer adjustbox. Try to use `example-image` as the inage (as that is generally available for this sort of test) and make an example that is not spaced as you expect, then someone can fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You can add *horizontal* padding between the images by using `\hspace{<value>}` between them, not `\vspace`!

Also instead of `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` and `\includegraphics` simply skip the `export` option and use `\adjustimage` directly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mwe}% for the example text and images only

\newcommand\vastehoogte[1]{%
    \adjustimage{height=\textheight}{#1}%
}
\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
        \vastehoogte{example-image-a}\hspace{10mm}%
        \vastehoogte{example-image-b}\hspace{10mm}%
        \vastehoogte{example-image-c}\hspace{10mm}%
        \vastehoogte{example-image-plain}\hspace{10mm}%
        \vastehoogte{example-image-empty}\hspace{10mm}%
        \vastehoogte{example-image}%
\end{adjustbox} 
\par

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

As `adjustbox` gives you also additional features you could use these as well of course, e.g. the `margin=<left> <bottom> <right> <top>` key to add the spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand\vastehoogte[2][5mm 0mm 5mm 0mm]{%
    \adjustimage{height=\textheight,margin={#1}}{#2}%
}
\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{adjustbox}{max width=1\textwidth}
        \vastehoogte[0mm 0mm 5mm 0mm]{example-image}
        \vastehoogte{example-image}
        \vastehoogte{example-image}
        \vastehoogte{example-image}
        \vastehoogte{example-image}
        \vastehoogte[5mm 0mm 0mm 0mm]{example-image}
\end{adjustbox} 
\par

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]